# How to update ECS-service forming a Hazelcast cluster group gracefully?

Tags: hazelcast, amazon-ecs

We have an ECS-service (EC2 ECS) with several tasks forming a Hazelcast cluster group (hazelcast:3.10.6, hazelcast-aws:2.2, we use Hazelcast for storing some shared data and locks in distributed objects). It uses rolling service update with minimum healthy percent set to 100, and maximum at 200.

Updating this service with new Task Definition is not very reliable - often Hazelcast can't preserve existing cluster due to the nature of ECS's service updating process. It sometimes removes tasks with old task definitions very quickly, often several at a time, breaking Hazelcast cluster group.

Yes, we can refactor the service to use client-server model to store memory grid in a separate service or use alternatives, such as storing locks in Redis, but it would be interesting to listen someone who already faced similar difficulties and found a way to gracefully update Hazelcast-enabled services in ECS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make Hazelcast reliable on basically any containerized environment, you need to define **graceful shutdown**. That would prevent any data loss or multiple Hazelcast instances killed at the same time.

In order to do it, you can check [ECS doc about StopTask](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_StopTask.html) and [Hazelcast documentation on Graceful Shutdown](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-docker#graceful-shutdown). In short, you need to:

- Add `hazelcast.shutdownhook.policy=GRACEFUL` to `JAVA_OPTS`
- Add `hazelcast.graceful.shutdown.max.wait=<max-waiting-time-for-data-migration>` to `JAVA_OPTS`
- Change `ECS_CONTAINER_STOP_TIMEOUT` env variable to `<max-waiting-time-for-data-migration>`

If you store a lot of data in the Hazelcast cluster, you can set the value `max-waiting-time-for-data-migration` to a high number, like even a few hours.